# Mapping a list of inputs to the lowest level of nested lists

Tags: python-2.7, nested

I have a class in Python, which stores more of its kind inside of itself, as a jagged tree structure. The highest and middle layers don't store any data, but the lowest level does. I have a list such as `[8, 2, 5, 3]`, and I want to assign each value to its corresponding slot at the lowest level of the tree: [image: tree] Each node can have a different number of connections downwards, and there can be any number of layers. My problem is, I can't use the `traverse` function presented in similar questions because I am assigning multiple values, and I can't easily get the index of each value at the bottom. Here is the node class:

```
    class Node(object):
        def __init__(self, branches):
            self.branches = branches # This is a list of Node objects
            self.value = 0
```

The branch list contains more Nodes, which have lists of Nodes themselves. The value defaults to 0, but as stated before will have a list mapped to them later on. Here is an example of how to create a tree, and what I want to do:

```
tree = Node([
        Node([
            Node([
                None # This node's value is 1
            ]),
            Node([
                None # This node's value is 2
            ])
        ]),

        Node([
            Node([
                None # This node's value is 3
            ]),
            Node([
                None # This node's value is 4
            ])
        ])
    ])

    tree.set_inputs([1, 2, 3, 4]) # See above comments, this is what I want
```

How can I accomplish this? My only idea is a recursive function that turns the index of the input into a binary (this may change based on number of branches) number such as `0100110` that determines which direction to take at each recurse by indexing its branches:

```
# In the example above: b0 -> b1 -> b0 -> b0 -> b1 -> b1 -> b0.
```

If this is the way to go about this, I need some help implementing it. Otherwise, any help regarding my problem is appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of questions that need to be answered before we can help. What does your code look like? Are the children of a node ordered? Is the order in which you assign values to the leaf nodes important, or does it only matter that each value is assigned?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sorry I forgot about a code example. I have edited the question to include one. Also, the order is important. From left to right or right to left is irrelevant, only that it stays consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A depth-first search can be done in such a way as to yield the leaf nodes of the tree in order from left-to-right or right-to-left, depending on how it is implemented. First, I'm going to add a `name` attribute and a `__repr__` to your `Node` to make it easier to see what is happening:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, branches):
        self.branches = branches # This is a list of Node objects
        self.value = 0
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Node {}>'.format(self.name)
```

Now we'll define two functions. The first yields the nodes in a depth-first search:

```
from collections import deque

def dfs(root):
    stack = deque([root])
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        yield node
        if node.branches is not None:
            for child in reversed(node.branches):
                stack.append(child)
```

Note some things about this code. First, we iterate over the `reversed` children of the node. This results in the leaves being yielded from left-to-right. If we remove `reversed`, the leaves will be iterated over from right-to-left. Also, note that perhaps a cleaner representation for a leaf node without any children is to assign an empty iterable, such an empty tuple, to `node.branches`. Then the `node.branches is not None` check can be removed completely.

The above code generates *all* nodes, of course. We just want the leaves:

```
def leaves(root):
    for node in dfs(root):
        if node.branches is None:
            yield node
```

Let's test it out. Here's a simple tree:

```
#      g
#     / \   
#    /   \
#   e     f
#  /\    /\
# a  b  c  d

a, b, c, d = [Node(name, None) for name in 'abcd']
e = Node('e', (a,b))
f = Node('f', (c,d))
g = Node('g', (e,f))
```

And let's list the leaves:

```
>>> list(leaves(g))
[<Node a>, <Node b>, <Node c>, <Node d>]
```

Note that they are in order from left-to-right. Now assigning values is easy:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for leaf, value in zip(leaves(g), values):
    leaf.value = value
```

So that:

```
for node in (a, b, c, d):
    print(node.name, node.value)
```

gives:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```